# Aria del dipendente

Tags: puns

Listening to Alessandro Scarlatti's aria "O cessate di piagarmi", the pun "Non cessate di pagarmi" came to my mind. Since my Italian skills are pretty limited, I wonder if

1. the sentence makes sense from a grammatical point of view,
2. the intended context is clear (something one would jokingly say to their boss),
3. it is funny.

Also, I think that "O cessate di piagarmi" is definitely worth listening to.

Comment: I'd remove parts 2. and 3. as exceedingly opinion-based. What's funny? How do we say what “one” would say to their boss? (Now? In Scarlatti's time?) The first question, on the other hand, seems legitimate.

Comment: If you sang it like the aria is supposed to be sung, some people might well find it funny, i.e. parts 2 and 3 optional.

Comment: Is the pun “Non cessate di pagarmi” yours? Or are you quoting someone?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it does.
2. No, since employer-employee relations are regulated by contracts, not by querulous musical requests. The only exception might be if, rather than in a real-life situation, you are imagining this in a fantasy, Leporello/Don Giovanni-like situation. In that case, I refer you to Lorenzo Da Ponte for better gags and jokes.
3. Not quite. I'm not sure where its funniness is supposed to be. Just because a sentence sound sort-of-vaguely-like another one, doesn't make it funny.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of “O cessate di piagarmi” is “Please, stop wounding me”, so there is no connection with “Non cessate di pagarmi”, that is, “Don't stop paying me”, unless you want to suggest that your job is very painful, which is what your boss would infer if he knows the original words of the aria.